# Apple Push notification, logging out app and deleting app problems/solutions

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Push notifications are working great for me except in one scenario. The app we are working on requires you login/logout, so when you are logged in, the server sends you notifications, and when you are not logged in, it shouldn't.

If a user deletes the app while logged in, the server doesn't know that the user has deleted the app. This isn't a problem if the app stays deleted and the server attempts to send a notification- the APNS feedback mechanism on the server side catches this and closes the session.

What if the user reinstalls the app? They are still logged in from the server's perspective. On app startup, you can send a log me out message to the server. What if you don't start the app? The app will still see notifications coming in!

Is this a stupid edge case I shouldn't worry about? Or is there an accepted way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the best way to fix this issue would to make a set ammount of time (maybe a week or 2) that if the user doesnt use the app or the server doesn't receive any data from the user, it logs them out.

That way it logs them out automatically and they would have to sign in when using the app again if they havent used it for 2 weeks

Answer (score 0):

you can do one thing , when the device sends the notifications register request to the server , server can check for UDID of the device and if founds any notifications the server can clear it out.

Comment: you can't check the udid anymore in the device to send it to the server

Comment: This is more or less what we're currently doing. There's still a way to get a udid off the device.

Comment: @nflacco how to get UDID in ios9